# Application-Level Rate Limiting, Total Time Usage computation

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, rate-limiting

In our application which uses a Facebook Graph API, in the Application-Level Rate Limiting dashboard, we can track three parameters: Call Count Usage Rate, Total Time Usage Rate, and Total CPU Time Usage. 
I've noticed that our application very often exceeds a Total Time Usage Rate. 
Unfortunately, I couldn't find how it is calculated a Total Time Usage available for our application calls. 
Does anyone know how is computed?

I've tried to find this info in official documentation, but there is only explained how Call Count Usage is calculated.

Facebook documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/rate-limiting/

Comment: You have any answers?

Answer (score 1):

Having a similar issue with my app, from what I understand youre requesting too much information from their api, ie your "query" has a big impact, I had a similar issue so I filtered to just the fields I needed, put requests into try/catch blocks and if I got a response code of 4 "Application request limit reached" I just backed off on my calls by simply using `sleep(180)`

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/rate-limiting/

I hope this helps